Flutter custom background service
I want to create a background service to check for an URL and send a notification to the user if the status code was 200.
I have two problems:

The annoying notification for Foreground Service (that if I don't send it, my service will not work when user closes the app)
I want to be able to give the url from the dart file to my kt file.

Here's the code:
Main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.background_service');

  Future<void> startService() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('startService');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to start service: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Background Service Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              startService();
            },
            child: Text('Start Service'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

MainActivity.kt
package com.example.flutter_application_1

import android.content.Intent // Import Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.background_service"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "startService") {
                startService(Intent(this, BackgroundService::class.java))
                result.success(null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}

and the code for background service
BackgroundService.kt
package com.example.flutter_application_1
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import java.io.IOException

class BackgroundService : Service() {
    private val mHandler: Handler = Handler()
    private val mRunnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            checkURL("http://URL")
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000) // Run every 1 second
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startForegroundService()
        mHandler.post(mRunnable)
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun checkURL(url: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build()

            try {
                client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val content = response.body?.string() ?: ""
                        sendNotification("URL Response", content)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationId = 1
        val channelId = "background_service_channel"
        val channelName = "Background Service Channel"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelId = "background_service_channel"
        val channelName = "Background Service Channel"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    
    val notification = createNotification()
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val channelId = "background_service_channel"
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Running...")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        return notificationBuilder.build()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678
    }
}

I couldn't find anything on the net so I hope if I get an answer, it will benefit others, too.
This is a haunted issue that won't let me sleep.
